# SQL error when using Group By: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql, group-by

I've been getting this error when doing what I thought to be one of the simplest possible queries! I see other people have run into issues here too, and I've looked through every solution I've seen but they're with more involved queries so it was very hard for me to pick out the problem. I made a little dummy table to illustrate my problem.

table name: grouptest

```
id  name
1   Mel
2   Lucy
3   Mandy
4   Mel
5   Mandy
6   Mel
```

I want to find out how many times each name shows up, to produce a table like:

```
3 Mel
2 Mandy
1 Lucy
```

Here's the query I think should work:

```
SELECT Count(id), Name
FROM groupbytest
GROUP BY 'Name'
```

And I get the error:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not
>   an outer reference.

Help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have quotes around the Name field which are unneeded.

```
SELECT Count(id), Name
FROM grouptest
GROUP BY Name
```

Based on your comments, you need to `CAST` your `Name` column:

```
SELECT Count(id), Cast(Name as Varchar(max)) Name
FROM grouptest
GROUP BY Cast(Name as Varchar(max))
```

Comment: Yes! that worked perfectly :) If you have time, could you explain why that worked/is necessary? Also thank you for such a quick response.

Comment: @Mel the problem was that you were trying to group the data by a datatype that is not allowed. You had either a text, ntext or image field in your table.  You need to use a datatype that can be grouped.  I used the `varchar(max)` to convert your data to a type that is allowed. You could have cast it to a `nvarchar(max)` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Lose the `'` on the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Count(id), Name 
FROM groupbytest 
GROUP BY Name
```

If `name` is a `text`, then you need to cast it to `VARCHAR`, but you might be truncating your column.

```
SELECT Count(id), CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS Name
FROM groupbytest 
GROUP BY CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(8000))
```

Comment: If I lose the 's, I get this error: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: @Mel - In that case, the message is clear. You can't group by a column of that datatype. You can try casting to `VARCHAR` first

Comment: @bluefeet - :-) you also beated me on one today

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
SELECT Count(id), [Name]
FROM groupbytest 
GROUP BY [Name]
```

`GROUP BY 'Name'` tries to group on the literal string 'Name', not the column `Name`.

`Name` also may be a reserved word, hence the brackets around it, although you're better off not calling the column `Name`.

Comment: I changed the column name just to eliminate that possibility, but adding brackets gives me the same error as when I don't have 's The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Comment: Then you need to cast the `Name` column to a varchar.