# Error in Group by query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I know this question have been asked many times! But I still I could not solve the problem.

I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746835/sql-error-when-using-group-by-each-group-by-expression-must-contain-at-least-on) and add Cast to my query and it did not help.

my query is:

```
SELECT *, sum(sumofcomments) as allcomments
FROM k4 
group by user
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include all non-aggregated columns in your `GROUP BY` clause. Example of a valid query would be

```
select c1, c2, c3, sum(c4) as c4_total
from myTable
group by c1, c2, c3
```

So instead of selecting `*`, you would need to select named columns and include all columns apart from `sumofcomments` in both the `select` list and the `group by` list. Also, can you confirm that the column `sumofcomments` in your table `k4` is a numeric data type - otherwise you can't sum it.